# Load local HTML file into a WebBrowser control from my.resources in the project - vb.net

Tags: html, vb.net, treeview, browser, controls

```
 If TreeView1.SelectedNode.Name = 2 Then
        WebBrowser1.Url = My.Resources.Welcome
 End If
```

and it doesn't work so if you could please provide an example.

Also i don't really know how the treeview control works, i know with the combo box or listbox you just have an index of 0, 1, 2, 3 etc. but with the treeview you don't any just one of the things I want to do is whenever the root node is selected i want it to deselect that and select the node that I specify like node.name = 2.

I'm using visual basic 2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [DocumentText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documenttext.aspx) Property:

```
If TreeView1.SelectedNode.Name = 2 Then 
  WebBrowser1.DocumentText = My.Resources.Welcome
End If
```